# Nvidia Driver issues with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Jammy, Kernel:5.15.53-generic

Tags: drivers, kernel, 22.04, cuda

While trying to update my Cuda driver and toolkit using the following [link](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=22.04&target_type=deb_local), i am getting the below error

```
$ sudo apt-get install cuda
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-520 : Depends: nvidia-settings (>= 520.61.05) but it is not installable
 nsight-systems-2022.4.2 : Depends: libtinfo5 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Also, i tried to install cuda driver using the .run file from the same link, it did work but it seems the cuda toolkit are not installed.
I use

```
$ nvcc --version 
Command 'nvcc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Will appreacite if someone can help me !

Answer (score 0):

Hey I caught into the same issue on my office PC so I fixed it by using command

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

and looking at the conflicting dependencies.
and removing dependencies one by one.
I know it was a hectic work but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a way, after checking the boxes in the  ubuntu software tab for download from the internet as in the figure
[software updater](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dABzw.png)

then reboot the system. After that, I could reinstall the Cuda-toolkit-1.8 with drivers having all the features.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).